# How to delete one or multiple rows with a checkbox in a MysQl database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm pretty new to programming. I hope that you guys will be able to help me on this. that would be cool ^^. I have a table in a mysql database where I'm trying to delete each rows with a checkbox of my database using a delete button, I tried to use an Ajax function in order to delete the rows with checkboxes without refreshing the code but it does not seem to work, I checked on other posts as well but the solutions does not seem to apply to what I want to do. So, here is my code:

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <!-- Encodage des caractères à destination des navigateurs -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>User manager</title>
  
  <!-- Element de lien vers le lien cdn bootstrap css -->
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css'>

  
  
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Gestion du site</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Begin page content -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <br>
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    
    <form class="form-inline" action="">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="search">Rechercher Table Trouver:</label>
        <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_name" placeholder="search by name"> -->
        <input type="text"  id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunctionTrouver()"  class="table-search" placeholder="Je recherche...">
        <button id="search_button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Soumettre</button>
        <button id="button_delete1" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Supprimer</button>
        <a class="delete_data" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </form>
    
<br>
    <?php
include("displayManagerTrouver.php");
?>



<br>
<br>

<form class="form-inline" action="">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="search">Rechercher Table Chercher:</label>
        <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_name" placeholder="search by name"> -->
        <input type="text"  id="myInput1" onkeyup="myFunctionChercher()"  class="table-search" placeholder="Je recherche...">
        <button id="search_button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Soumettre</button>
        <button id="btn_delete" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-row_id="58">Supprimer</button>
      </div>
    </form>

    <br>

<?php
include("displayManagerChercher.php");
?>


<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted"> </p>
  </div>
</footer>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
  
<!-- script search bar trouver -->
    <script>
    function myFunctionTrouver() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
    </script>

<!-- script search bar chercher -->
    <script>
    function myFunctionChercher() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput1");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable1");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".delete_data").click(function(){
   var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
   var parent = $(this).parent();
   $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'displayManagerTrouver.php',
      data:'delete_id='+del_id,
      success:function(data) {
        if(data) { parent.slideUp(300,function() {
                parent.remove();
        } else { // Error }
      }
   });
 });
});



</body>

</html>
```

```html
<html>
<?php
// Ajouter la connection a la bd
include "Connection.php";

// Sélectionne les données avec PDO plus des requêtes préparés
echo "<table id='myTable' style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<tr><th>Prénom</th><th>Nom</th><th>Photo</th><th>Description</th><th>E-mail</th><th>type d'objet</th><th>date de l'objet trouvé</th><th></th></tr>";

// Après avoir selectionné les colonnes de la table voulu il affiche les données dans un tableau HTML
// RecursiveIteratorIterator est utilisé pour itérer sur des itérateurs, récursivement.
class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
    function __construct($it) { 
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td style='width: 200px; border: 1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() { 
        echo "<tr>";

    } 

    function endChildren() { 
        echo '<td><input type="checkbox" value = "aria-label"/></td>';
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    } 
} 

try {
    // Sélectionne les données à afficher de la base de données trouver
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, lname, photo, objet_description, email, objet_type, date_objet FROM trouver"); 
    $stmt->execute();

     // le tableau resulte en un tableau associatif
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
        echo $v;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";


$id = $_POST['checkbox'];
$query = "delete from trouver where ID = $id";

?> 
</html>
```

thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but this defies the whole idea of Stackoverflow. By us writing the code for you, you wouldn't actually be learning coding at all. It's better to read documentation, try to implement something, and when something fails, try to google that, or ask a question related to that specific error in your implementation.

Comment: I never asked to write the code for me my code is right there. I just wanted some help. but thanks anyways